# A way to merge the content of two text files into one with a delimiter to differentiate that the content is from two different files

Tags: python-3.x

This is the piece of code that will read the content from the files and then creates a dataframe. 
I need two dataframes to be created - one with contents of File1.txt and the other with the contents of File2.txt.

```
`Content of File1.txt`
Str1:123
   Str2:456

`Content of File1.txt`
Str1:789
   Str2:1011

Expected Dataframe:
  123 456 789 1011



file_name=['File1.txt','File2.txt']
string_to_search = ['Str1']
string_next= ['Str2']
list_of_results = []
list_of_results_1 = []

for item in file_name:
  with open(item, 'r') as read_obj:
    for line in read_obj:
        for set in string_to_search:
          if set in line:
            list_of_results.append(line.replace(" ", "").strip('\n').split(':'))
        for set1 in string_next:
            if set1 in line:
               list_of_results_1.append(line.replace(" ", "").strip('\n').split(':'))


for i in range(0, len(list_of_results)): list_of_results[i].extend(list_of_results_1[i])
print(list_of_results)
df = pd.DataFrame(list_of_results)
print(df)
```

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: @DavideBrex Instead of merging the files, I created a list of the file names and read each and performed the action. But it creates a single dataframe. I need 2 dataframes one for the first file and the other for the second. Can you please help in achieving this?

Comment: I can help you for sure. However, it is difficult to understand what your problem is. Please read this: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Then try to edit your question and make more clear what is your problem.

Comment: @DavideBrex Thanks for the link. I apologize for not framing it in an understandable manner. Now i hope it conveys the real issue I am facing.

Comment: You are welcome! Now it is more clear. I still have a couple of questions for you. I don't understand what are `string_to_search` and `string_next`. Could you also show an example of how is the content of `File1.txt` and File2.txt`? So you want as output a dataframe with 2 columns: the first column contains File1 (each line in the file as one row in the dataframe) and the second column contains File2? And finally you want to store this dataframe ?

Comment: @DavideBrex The first two columns are from the File1.txt and the other two are from File2.txt. Using the dataframe I am going to plot a graph for the data

Comment: @DavideBrex I am really grateful to you for the solution. Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

File 1:

```
Str1:123
Str2:456
Str1:1212
Str2:9999
```

File 2:

```
Str1:789
Str2:1011
Str1:0000
Str2:1000
```

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
file_name=['File1.txt','File2.txt']
string_to_search = ['Str1']
string_next= ['Str2']

list_df = []

for item in file_name:
  list_of_results = []
  list_of_results_1 = []
  with open(item, 'r') as read_obj:
    for line in read_obj:
        if "Str1" in line:
            list_of_results.append(line.replace(" ", "").strip('\n').split(':')[1])
        else:
            list_of_results_1.append(line.replace(" ", "").strip('\n').split(':')[1])
    list_df.append(pd.DataFrame({"Str1_"+item.split(".")[0]: list_of_results,"Str2_"+item.split(".")[0]:list_of_results_1}))

print(list_df[0])
print(list_df[1])
final_df = pd.concat([list_df[0],list_df[1]],axis = 1)
print(final_df)
```

Output (final_df, the 2 dataframes from each file are combined):

```
  Str1_File1 Str2_File1 Str1_File2 Str2_File2
0        123        456        789       1011
1       1212       9999       0000       1000
```

Single dataframe (one per each file)

File1:

```
  Str1_File1 Str2_File1
0        123        456
1       1212       9999
```

File2:

```
  Str1_File2 Str2_File2
0        789       1011
1       0000       1000
```